# Chrome Extensions Auto Clicker

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension it will get me to certain page by autoclicking. Since it goes from page to page. I am not able to get past after the first page. I am not able to do when the second page loads after first click

manifest.json

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "AutoClick",
"description": "This autoclicks",
"version": "1.1",

"background": {
    "scripts": [
        "background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": false
},
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches":    ["*://*.blogger.com/*"],
    "js":         ["content.js"],
    "run_at":     "document_end",
    "all_frames": false
}],
"permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "*://*.blogger.com/*"
    
    
]
```

}

background.js

```js
chrome.tabs.create

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
   
    var newURL = "https://draft.blogger.com/blog/posts/3778735982367012067";
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: newURL });
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({ file: "content.js" });
    
});
```

content.js

```js
function createpost(){
    document.querySelector('.CwaK9').click()
}
function video1(){
    document.querySelector('.vde74d').click()
}

if (window.location.href == "https://draft.blogger.com/blog/posts/3778735982367012067") {
    
    createpost()
    newFunction()

}



function newFunction() {

    
        if (window.location.href.match('https://draft.blogger.com/blog/posts/3778735982367012067/')) {
            
        video1();
        
    
}
}
```

using match because it add random ID to end of the URL after first click.
It works fine during first click but when the next page loads it don't.